# C# compiler error for single line if statement with 2 actions

Tags: c#, if-statement, compiler-errors

It was hard to find a good title explaining the issue. I will try to explain the problem in detail. I try to use a single line if statement with 2 actions inside another if statement. However, this usage fails the parent if statement's result.

Before going into deep I have to stress that the method below **returns FALSE**:

```
draggedItem.GetComponent<PreparedItem> ().CheckPreparationAvailability ()
```

The method above is included inside two if clauses below. Therefore I expect the result **FALSE** immediately. The only changing part is the last statement, focus there.

**Problematic version without parentheseses**:

```
if (acceptedTypeID == draggedItem.CurrentTypeID.foodTypePart1
        && draggedItem.GetComponent<PreparedItem> () != null 
        && draggedItem.GetComponent<PreparedItem> ().CheckPreparationAvailability () // RETURNS FALSE, DO NOT FORGET
        && rootTransform.GetComponentsInChildren<DragAndDropItem> ().Length <= 0
        && draggedItem.RootTransform.GetComponentInChildren<PlateCell>()
        && (true)? true : true) { // problem here 

        'if' is considered as TRUE and the inside is executed ...


}
```

**Working version with parentheseses**:

```
if (acceptedTypeID == draggedItem.CurrentTypeID.foodTypePart1
        && draggedItem.GetComponent<PreparedItem> () != null 
        && draggedItem.GetComponent<PreparedItem> ().CheckPreparationAvailability () // RETURNS FALSE, DO NOT FORGET
        && rootTransform.GetComponentsInChildren<DragAndDropItem> ().Length <= 0
        && draggedItem.RootTransform.GetComponentInChildren<PlateCell>()
        && ((true)? true : true)) { // WORKS AS EXPECTED 

        'if' is considered as FALSE which is expected and the inside is NOT executed ...


}
```

Comment: Don't focus on that part. It is there to simplify the issue. Because 'draggedItem.GetComponent<PreparedItem> ().CheckPreparationAvailability ()' returns FALSE, remaning true values are meaningless. PS: this comment was an explanation to someones' comment -_-

Comment: What do you even want to express by `&& (true)? true : true`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider this:

```
bool a = true;
bool b = false;

Console.WriteLine(a && b && (true) ? true : true);   // Prints true
Console.WriteLine(a && b && ((true) ? true : true)); // Prints false
```

This happens because [the precedence of the `?:` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/) is such that in the first WriteLine above, it is as if you wrote this:

```
(a && b && (true)) ? true : true
```

which is always going to result in `true`.

The second, of course, is parenthesized so that it works as you expected.

Comment: By seeing them on one line, this appears more clearly. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Without the explicit parentheses the statement is executed the same way as if the parentheses would be placed as following, as everything left of the `?` is considered as the condition for the inline-if:

```
if ((acceptedTypeID == draggedItem.CurrentTypeID.foodTypePart1
        && draggedItem.GetComponent<PreparedItem> () != null 
        && draggedItem.GetComponent<PreparedItem> ().CheckPreparationAvailability () // RETURNS FALSE, DO NOT FORGET
        && rootTransform.GetComponentsInChildren<DragAndDropItem> ().Length <= 0
        && draggedItem.RootTransform.GetComponentInChildren<PlateCell>()
        && (true)) ? true : true)
```

So your second example is the valid solution for such a case.